# Laravel 4: Auth credentials with two optional value to user type

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4, cartalyst-sentry

I have 3 types of users:

1. Client
2. Admin
3. Super Admin

Now, I need to allow both `admin` and `super admin` to login in my admin portal how ever to implement the authentication we are going to put in array form our credentials like:

```
$creds = array('username'=>Input::get('uname'),'password'=>Input::get('pwd'),'usertype'=>$utype);
```

How can I allow both `admin` and `super admin` in `Auth` if I am only allowed to declare `usertype` once in my `$creds` array?

Comment: Rob below gives some direction on what you should do, but we need more information to help answer you more concretely. Why/how is only being able to define 'usertype' once a limitation?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apply some groups to your users, add the user to a group and validate on that.
( Or even, apply ACL to groups, and check on that )
Is the future requires more types of users you can just add them to a group instead of altering your $creds array.

Answer (score 0):

we all know that if we are going to attemp an authnetication, we are going to pass an array of credetials. My problem my `usertype` can have two value( `admin` and `super admin` ) but we cant put two `usertype` in an array like this:

```
$creds = array('username'=>$uname,'password'=>$pwd,'usertype'=>'admin','usertype'=>'super admin');
```

SOLUTION: The only way for this is grouping it(as of the moment I think.)

```
Route::filter('admin-auth', function(){
if(Auth::guest() || Auth::user()->usertype == 'client' || Auth::user()->active == 0) return Redirect::to('admin/login?ret='.Request::url());
});
```

NOTE: the `Redirect::to('admin/login?ret='.Request::url())` is not advisable because laravel has already the `Redirect::intended()` function if you are going to redirect someone to a certain page after successful authentication however I did this because Im using ajax.

Answer (score -1):

You can use a little trick that i found. on credentials array you can add DB::RAW to your condition like this:

```
$creds = array(
                'username'=> Input::get('uname'),
                'password'=> DB:RAW(Input::get('pwd') . ' and `usertype` in (your user types);
```

Maybe not the best solution but it works. You can check your query to see that it's ok